# Google pay refund API found nowhere

Tags: java, android, google-api, payment, google-pay

In my application I am about to implement google pay but I have doubt regarding how to initiate refund for user...I have gone through google pay API but I nowhere found a word refund..

https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/tutorial

he payment merchant that we are using is Paytab (it is also helping us process Apple Pay payment and refund) but does not support google pay.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

As you point out, Paytabs isn't a supported Google Pay PSP. Unfortunately, there isn't an easy way to get Google Pay integration going with Paytabs.

That said, there is a difficult way to do it using DIRECT integration but it comes with it's own set of problems: https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/test-and-deploy/integration-checklist#testing-your-integration

But back to your original question about refunds, Google Pay doesn't process the payment, your payment processor does. That's why you can't find a reference to it in the documentation. Charges and refunds will need to be initiated through your payment processor.